# Default django project not showing django templates

Tags: python, css, django

I started a new Django project with a new superuser. While I am able to access the admin interface, it does not have any of the default CSS files. It is looking for them in an admin/ folder within my static/ folder, but I do not have an admin/ folder anywhere in my project. How can I add the default CSS files for the admin interface?

Comment: You mean there is no css applied to your admin interface? The files are not found (404) ?

Comment: That's correct, @RodrigoDela

Answer (score 1):

You don't need one unless you want to change the default styles.
Your static resources for admin interface located in your django installation folder (site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin).

It will be automatically be used by django framework unless you've done some extra settings that ruined default behaviour.

check for the following items in your settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ...
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ...
)

...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
```

If you want to add some extra static folder/files:

```
# define global static
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

You can also have in each app a static folder like this

> your_project_folder/your_app_folder/static/your_app_name/[static_resources]

If you're on production server and not development consider also adding a proper STATIC_ROOT like this

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"
```

in your setting file or production server specific settings location.

> At last check for django docs for specific version that you're using
>   [mine in 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup your `STATIC_ROOT` and your `STATIC_URL`.

After that run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```